# Does anyone know how elastic and paralax efects work in table view in ios7

Tags: tableview, ios7, parallax

Does anyone know how elastic and parallax effects work in table view in ios7

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're talking about the Messages app and when you scroll up and down the message bubbles are fluidly elastic.

Apple did this with a `UICollectionViewController` actually and using UIKit Dynamics between each cell (message bubble).

You should check out the UIKit Dynamics WWDC video to know how to do this in great detail. That's where they said they used a collection view and not a table view.

Answer (score 0):

Parallax: UIMotionEffects (you can use UIInterpolatingMotionEffect on center.x and center.y key paths like explained here: http://kevinyavno.com/blog/?p=127 )

I don't know exactly what you mean with elastic but you probably want to use UIKit dynamics. there are a lot of WWDC Videos about that. you'll be looking for the classes UIDynamicAnimator, UIGravityBehavior, UICollisionBehavior and UIDynamicItemBehavior (to modify elasticity of items).

There are 2 videos on this, found here: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/

Answer (score 0):

For all the physics related motion you will have to either use box2d or UIKit Dynamics in iOS7.

Here is a good tutorial for [UIKit Dynamics For iOS 7](http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/uikit-dynamics-ios7-tutorial/)